# Как передать arguments вложенной функции?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Нужно сделать функцию, которая принимает две функции (простые мат.операции), объединяет их в одну и возвращает её. Одна из входящих функций может принимать некоторое количество аргументов. А результирующая функция должна иметь возможность принимать аргументы, чтобы направлять их на вход этой вложенной.

```
function funcGen(func1, func2) {
return function(/*возможные аргументы*/) {
    return func1(func2(/*возможные аргументы*/))
}}
```

Я знаю о псевдомассиве `arguments`, но не понимаю, как передать его элементы на вход `func2`. Я бы передал их массивом, но тогда `func2` должна быть заранее к этому готова, а такого условия нет в задаче.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, хотите что-то такого рода?:

```js
function pow2(a) {
  return a * a;
}

function sum() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

function collapseFunctions(f1, f2) {
  return function() {
    return f1(f2.apply(this, arguments));
  }
}

console.log(collapseFunctions(pow2, sum)(1, 2, 3));
```

Функция `f1` принимает 1 параметр, я сделал функцию, которая принимает 1 аргумент и возводит его в квадрат - `pow2`.

Функция `f2` принимает любое количество параметров, в данном случае я сделал функцию, которая считает сумму всех переданных параметров.

Функция `collapseFunctions` принимает `f1` и `f2`, вызывает `f2` и передает результат ее работы как аргумент для `f1`. Потом все, что насчитала `f1`, возвращается вам.

Для анонимной функции внутри `collapseFunction` я не объявлял параметры, ибо они берутся из `arguments`. Чтобы пробросить псевдомассив `arguments` в функцию `f2`, я использую функцию `apply`.

Как-то так. Надеюсь, что понял, что вы хотите.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Функция `f2` в моем примере не обязательно должна работать с псевдомассивом `arguments`. Она может явно объявлять нужные ей параметры. Они будут доставлены ей в любом случае. Например, пусть берет лишь два параметра - `a` и `b`:

```js
function pow2(a) {
  return a * a;
}

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function collapseFunctions(f1, f2) {
  return function() {
    return f1(f2.apply(this, arguments));
  }
}

console.log(collapseFunctions(pow2, sum)(1, 2));
```

Comment: Спасибо, это в точности то, что нужно.
Один вопрос: в this разве не f1 должен оказаться в итоге?

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo не увидел обновление вашего комментария) Смотрите: я обращаюсь к `this` внутри анонимной функции. А эту анонимную функцию я возвращаю из `collapseFunctions`. И в итоге у вас на руках просто анонимная функция. Если ее вызывать так, как я сделал в примере - простой вызов, то значение `this` внутри нее будет ссылаться на `window` - значение по умолчанию. (только если не используется `use strict`). Чтобы изменить значение `this`, вы можете его привязать к этой анонимной функции через `bind`.